# What is the meaning of "Schlängelgang"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What does "Schlängelgang" mean? I wasn't able to find it anywhere. This is from Fontane's *Stine*:

> Ich verstehe mich ein bißchen auf das menschliche Herz; denn sieh, wer jahrelang auf dem Krankenbett liegt, der hat viel Zeit und spürt vielem nach, und das Verlockendste sind immer die **Schlängelgänge** des Herzens, des eignen und des der andern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means walking in meandering lines. *Schlängelgang* comes from *geschlängelt* (meandering, snake-like), which comes from *Schlange* (snake), referencing the sinuous way snakes move.

> das Verlockendste sind immer die Schlängelgänge des Herzens

You could roughly translate this as

> the most tempting are always the meandering walks of the heart

or, as Takkat suggested, more poetically,

> the winding trails of the heart.

Answer (score 4):

From few references available there may be two meanings than can either be a [movement in a winding or snake like fashion](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=schlaengelgang), or it can have the meaning of a [path that meanders like a labyrinth](http://www.zeit.de/1976/51/denken-und-irren). For both meanings usage is rare.

As for a translation of Fontane's poetic usage let me suggest a similar proverb like:

> [wound] trails of the heart